# Correct way to merge jQuery event methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to optimize my code.

I current have two separate calls w/ a block of code that does near enough the same thing for each. I know if I was looking at two separate items with the same event method (e.g. .click), I could simply add the additional selector in.

However I am using both on click and on change.

EDIT: The #walking and #driving are radio buttons and the #narrow is a select box.

This is what I have currently:

```js
// When a place type is selected
$('#narrow').on('change', function() {
    
    // Clear the current results
    $('#place_results_wrap').empty();
    
    // Show progress
    
    $('#place_results_wrap').html('' +
        '<div id="load_container">' +
            '<div id="load">' +
            '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading</span>' +
            '<div id="status"><h3>Please wait...</h3></div>' +
        '</div>');
    
    
    // Temp disable the narrow
    $("#narrow").prop("disabled", true);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#narrow").prop("disabled", false); 
    }, 15000);
    
    // Grab the current transport method
    var mode = $('input[name=travelmode]:checked').val().toLowerCase();
    
    // Load page into results div
    $('#place_results_wrap').load('/assets/php/places.php?type=' + this.value + '&mode=' + mode, '&latlon=' + latlon, function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".place_results").offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
    
    
// If the travel type is changed
$('#walking, #driving').click(function(){
    
    // Grab the current place type
    var place_type = $('select#narrow').val();
    
    // If it has been specified
    if(place_type)
    {
        // Clear the current results
        $('#place_results_wrap').empty();
            
        // Show progress
        
        $('#place_results_wrap').html('' +
            '<div id="load_container">' +
                '<div id="load">' +
                '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading</span>' +
                '<div id="status"><h3>Please wait...</h3></div>' +
            '</div>');

        // Temp disable the travel type
        $("#driving, #walking").prop("disabled", true);
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#driving, #walking").prop("disabled", false);
        }, 15000);
    
        // Grab the current category    
        var type = $('select#narrow').val();
        
        // Grab the current transport method
        var mode = this.value.toLowerCase();    
        
        // Load page into results div
        $('#place_results_wrap').load('/assets/php/places.php?type=' + type + '&mode=' + mode, '&latlon=' + latlon, function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".place_results").offset().top
            }, 500);
        });    
    }
});
```

Is there a way for me to merge the #narrow change and #walking, #driving click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like so:

Create a function with the *change* event handler:

```
// When a place type is selected
function onChange() {
    // Clear the current results
    $('#place_results_wrap').empty();

    // Show progress

    $('#place_results_wrap').html('' +
        '<div id="load_container">' +
            '<div id="load">' +
            '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading</span>' +
            '<div id="status"><h3>Please wait...</h3></div>' +
        '</div>');


    // Temp disable the narrow
    $("#narrow").prop("disabled", true);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#narrow").prop("disabled", false); 
    }, 15000);

    // Grab the current transport method
    var mode = $('input[name=travelmode]:checked').val().toLowerCase();

    // Load page into results div
    $('#place_results_wrap').load('/assets/php/places.php?type=' + this.value + '&mode=' + mode, '&latlon=' + latlon, function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".place_results").offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
}

$('#narrow').on('change', onChange);
```

In your *click* event, you just call the function defined for the *change* event:

```
// If the travel type is changed
$('#walking, #driving').click(function(){

    // Grab the current place type
    var place_type = $('select#narrow').val();

    // If it has been specified
    if(place_type)
    {
        onChange();    
    }
});
```

The code is the same, you have only a check.

Comment: Modified slightly but this is exactly what I was after. Didn't think to call a function for both.